# Is there a generic way to test if an object exists in the DB?

Tags: entity-framework, generics, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

EF6 provides generic ways to control DB state through `DbContext.Entry(object).XXX` as opposed to `DbContext.Objects.XXX`

Is there a way to do this generically to test if an object exists? All I've come across would be calling `DbContext.Objects.Any(...)` and since my code-base is generic across about 6 different types this is a shame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Set<TEntity>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.set(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbContext.Set%60%601) generic method:

```
public bool Exist<T>(Expression<Func<T,bool>> condition)
{
   return context.Set<T>().Any(condition);
}
```